# Cómo concatenar variables en un template de Django usando tags

Tags: python, django

Estoy llamando en mi template a varias variables:

```
<p> {{ area.id }}  {{ area.departamento }} {{ area.encargado }} {{ area.descripcion }} </p>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es concatenarlas en una sola variable y contar el número de caracteres para que si sobrepasa determinado número que le asigne pueda indicarle a la cadena que se corte hasta ahí y no muestre más.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hasta donde sé eso no se puede hacer, lo que puedes hacer es retornar la cadena desde tu modelo haciendo uso de la función `__str__` o creando una función dentro de ese modelo, por ejemplo `full_information` que retorne una variable de tipo `string` que contenga la información.

Desde la plantilla llamas a esa función con el operador `.`, es decir, `area.full_information`, y luego si aplicas las respectivas etiquetas que necesitas para truncar la cadena.

Por ejemplo:

```
class area(models.Model):
    def get_full_information(self):
        return '%s %s %s ... %s' % (self.id, self.area, ... , self.descripcion)
```

Como puedes ver acá está la función, obtendrás una candena que concantena todos los campos que tu pongas en ella.

Cuando vayas a tu plantilla simplemente tienes que poner `{{ area.get_full_information }}` y con eso será suficiente, esa cadena puedes truncarla con las tags que quieras, las que se usan para eso, y listo. Obtienes una función útil en cualquier caso.

Comment: Hola, creo que lo mejor que puedes hacer es dar un ejemplo sobre lo que has descrito

Comment: Hola @salahaddhin, gracias por tu respuesta, me ha funcionado :)

Answer (score 5):

Existe un template tag llamado [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#add) pero que tal vez no funcione como quieras si estás mezclando enteros y cadenas:

```
{{ "!Hola, "|add:"Angie!" }} # Resultado: "!Hola, Angie!"
{{ 5|add:10 }} # Resultado: 15
{{ 5|add:"xyz" }} # Resultado: ""
```

No es recomendable en tu caso. Lo que puedes intentar es crear tu [propio template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters) mezclándolo con [`truncatechars`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars) algo parecido a esto:

```
# myapp/templatetags/extra_tags.py

from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import truncatechars


register = template.Library()    

@register.simple_tag
def add_args(*args, **kwargs):
    chars = kwargs.get('chars')
    return truncatechars(' '.join([str(arg) for arg in args]), chars)
```

Con esto podrías hacer algo así en tu template:

```
{% load extra_tags %}

<p>{% add_args 10 "Compras" "Angie Alejo" chars=20 %}</p>
```

El resultado sería:

```
<p>10 Compras Angie ...</p>
```

Puedes hacer lo mismo con los campos de tu modelo:

```
{% load extra_tags %}

<p>{% add_args area.pk area.departamento area.encargado chars=20 %}</p>
```

### Notas:

La estructura para crear template tags es:

```
myapp/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        extra_tags.py
    views.py
```

Es necesario que **reinicies tu servidor** para poder usar tu template tag.

Answer (score 2):

Lo resolví de la siguiente forma, gracias a los que respondieron y ayudaron:

En el modelo:

```
 def get_full_information(self): 
     return '%s %s %s' (self.description, self.boss, self.dept)
```

En el template:

```
 {{ area.details.get_full_information|truncatechars:30 }}
```

Comment: Muy bien! Solo hay un pequeño problema con esa solución, si luego deseas que la función `get_full_information` muestre un campo nuevo, vas a tener que actualizarla, reiniciar el servidor, etc.

Comment: Si, de hecho lo implementé de manera provisional, checaré bien la solución que me diste con las template tags porque las vi en un proyecto que trabajaré en el futuro pero como apenas estoy aprendiendo, muchas gracias @CésarBustíos :)